# Wakanda display in Grid the milliseconds in hour:minute:second

Tags: wakanda

Does anyone know how in Wakanda to display in Grid the milliseconds in hour:minute:second

I think it's the format in a Grid that i must modified but i don't know which format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the `onCurrentElementChange` event of the datasource that is associated with your grid:

```html
if (this.getCurrentElement()!==null){
 //format time value in data grid
 $$('dataGrid1').column('timeStamp').setRenderer( 
      function(myCell) {
        if (myCell.value > 0)
          return formatSeconds(myCell.value);//formatting using the ultility function 
   }
 );  
}
```

And then have the `formatSeconds` function in your code:

```html
function formatSeconds(milliseconds) {
     var date = new Date(1970,0,1);
     date.setSeconds(milliseconds/1000);
     return date.toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/, "$1");
 }
```